# How to Group By 2 fields in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, count, group-by

I have Two tables in Postgresql and I'm trying to get the number of times a hashtag is repeated by place.

I've made this query:

```
SELECT tweets_with_location.user_location, 
       tweets_with_location.my_new_id, 
       all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table
FROM tweets_with_location, all_hashtags_with_location
WHERE tweets_with_location.my_new_id = all_hashtags_with_location.my_new_id;
```

Which returns the Location, the tweet id and the hashtag:

> USER_LOCATION | MY_NEW_ID | HASHTAG
>
> New York, NY | 33 | Happy
>
> New York, NY | 40 | BigApple
>
> Bronx, NY | 12 | Happy
>
> Bronx, NY | 45 | Happy
>
> Queens, NY | 23 | Trump
>
> Queens, NY | 20 | Trump

Then, I've made another SQL Query but it seems it doesn't sums up the number of times a hashtag was displayed by place, the Count value is always 1:

```
SELECT tweets_with_location.user_location, 
       all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table,
       COUNT(DISTINCT all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table) AS CountOf 
FROM tweets_with_location, all_hashtags_with_location
WHERE tweets_with_location.my_new_id = all_hashtags_with_location.my_new_id
GROUP BY tweets_with_location.user_location, 
         all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table
ORDER BY CountOf DESC;
```

I need is this result:

> USER_LOCATION - HASHTAG - COUNT
>
> New York, NY | Happy | 1
>
> Bronx, NY | Happy | 2
>
> Queens, NY | Trump | 2
>
> New York, NY | Happy | 1

How do I do this? What is wrong with my SQL Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just remove the DISTINCT qualifier in the COUNT() function.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close, you are counting the wrong field:

```
SELECT tweets_with_location.user_location, 
       all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table,
       COUNT(DISTINCT tweets_with_location.my_new_id) AS CountOf 
FROM tweets_with_location, all_hashtags_with_location
WHERE tweets_with_location.my_new_id = all_hashtags_with_location.my_new_id
GROUP BY tweets_with_location.user_location, 
         all_hashtags_with_location.regexp_split_to_table
ORDER BY CountOf DESC;
```

Comment: This is the tweet id, not the hashtag id. Because one tweet can have like 3 hashtags or more... I'll try it anyways.

Comment: Seems like it worked, but I didn't understand why... can you please explain it to me? I want to learn it...

Comment: @JaquelinePassos -- it really depends on your data.  From your first post `my_new_id` are the fields you are trying to `count`.  However in your attempt, you were counting the distinct `hashtag` fields and grouping by them -- that will always return 1.  If you don't need the distinct count, you could just remove distinct and your query would work as well.  If there are duplicates and you don't want to count them multiple times, then go with this approach.